# Rules of syllabification

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, stress

In *Latin Grammar*, Robert J. Henle wrote (p. 2),

> Accent.
>
> 9. a. In words of two syllables the accent is on the first.
>      vía; béllum
> 10. b. In words of more than two syllables, if the second last syllable is long it is accented; otherwise the accent is on the third last syllable.
>       vidḗrunt; ágmĭne

Are there any exceptions to these rules? (I’m assuming that Latinized forms of foreign words will be the exception, but I am not certain.)

---

### References

Henle, Robert J. *Latin Grammar.* Chicago: Loyola Press, 1958.